# "SELECT * FROM $1" prepared statement errors to: error: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, pg, node-postgres

Why does this error?

```
 const response = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM $1`, [table]);
```

The value of `[table]` is `["person"]` in my test case. But it keeps erroring to:

```
error: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use placeholders (`$1`) for identifiers (such as column and table names), placeholders are just for values; you can think of it as the difference between `'name'` (a value) and `var name` (an identifier).

You can use string manipulation instead and you'll want to whitelist the identifier to avoid problems:

```
const safeTables = [ 'person', ... ]; // Known safe values.
if(!safeTables.includes(table)) {
    // throw an exception, return an error, ...
}

const response = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`);
```

This string interpolation is safe as you're only allowing known safe values though. You could also use a function that knows how to properly quote identifiers (such as `escape.ident` from [pg-escape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-escape)).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables for SQL Names/Identifiers, at least not with the basic driver.

Here's example of how this does work with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
const response = await db.query('SELECT * FROM $1:name', table);
```

or:

```
const response = await db.query('SELECT * FROM $1:name', [table]);
```

or:

```
const response = await db.query('SELECT * FROM ${table:name}', {table});
```

And there are many more variations possible, in terms of the [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) syntax and the kind of methods that you use.

Comment: Thanks! What does `:name` do?

Comment: @AskYous As per the link of [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) that I provided, it is a filter that makes the variable be interpreted as an sql name/identifier, and escaped accordingly.

Comment: Ah... Missed that. Thank you.

Comment: @AskYous So why did you remove the Accepted Answer from it?

Comment: @AskYous What didn't work? Are you going to provide details?